# Assigning local std::vector to reference in C++

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

I am not sure if my approach is correct. 
Since I am passing vector `v` by reference to `Function`, after it's execution vector's content will change.

What if I can't work directly on vector `v` and decide to use temporary vector `temp`. Is assigning to `v` my temporary through `v = temp` correct? Won't reference `v` point at some memory which will be swept after execution of `Function`?

```
void Function(std::vector<bool> &v) {
  std::vector<bool> temp(v.size(), false);

  // some operations on vector temp
  // ...

  v = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Won't reference `v` point at some memory which will be swept after execution of `Function`?

No. For `v = temp;`, `v` is copy assigned from `temp`. Then `v` will contain the same content with `temp`, but it has nothing to do with `temp`; `temp` is a local object which will be destroyed later, but the argument passed in won't be affected.

BTW: Since `temp` is a local object which will be destroyed when get out of the function, copying from it might be inefficient. You could move from it:

```
v = std::move(temp);
```

Comment: Wont compiler optimization automatically generate a move instead of copy since temp goes directly out of scope?

Comment: @A.S.H It might, it might not. This kind of optimization is not mentioned by the stardard, it's not guaranteed and not portable. So it's better to do it by ourselves to make it reliable.

Comment: If i try to use `v` after `Function` ends, should'nt it be unsafe because `v` is pointing to `temp` and `temp` no longer exists.Would it be any different if a pointer was used instead of reference.

Comment: @GauravSehgal No. Pointers are different with references. When you assign a reference, you're assigning the value of the variable pointed by the reference, not the reference itself. On the other hand, you can't rebind a reference to other variable. e.g. `int i = 0; int j = 1; int& r = i; r = j; j = 2;` then the value of `r` and `i` are both `1`, but `r` still bind to `i`, not `j`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Got it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assigning v = temp is safe. For further information look at e.g.: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs